# Retrieving the variable value to act as a name

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need an object in Typescript declared like this:

```
queryParameters = { flagged: true };
```

Now I would like to have the `flagged` to be retrieved from a variable name. Something like:

```
var param = 'flagged';
queryParameters = { ValueOf(param): true };
```

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
queryParameters = { [param]: true };
```

Comment: @DenysSéguret, actually there is a question, if a new object should be assigned, or just the property.